# Integration proeblem

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^{\infty} dr \, \cos{k r} \,= \frac12 \text{Re} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dr \, e^{i k r} \,$$

How can we write the above integral? 
$Re$ represents here the real part? 
Didi we do in the folllowing way $$\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} dr \, \cos{k r} \,=  \text{Re} \int_{-\infty}^{0} dr \, e^{i k r}  + \text{Re} \int_{0}^{\infty} dr \, \cos{k r} \,,$$

Comment: The integral doesn't converge. What is it that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Aside from Daniel's comment, you can write any integral in a lot of ways, what form or properties do you want once it's rewritten?

Comment: How the first line  and $Re$ arises and why?

Comment: Euler's formula says $e^{iz} = \cos z + i \sin z$. Setting $z = kr$, assuming $k$ (and $r$) real, we find $\cos (kr) = \operatorname{Re} e^{ikr}$. The factor $\frac12$ arises from the symmetry, so $\int_0^\infty \cos (kr)\,dr = \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos (kr)\,dr$, since $\cos$ is an even function.

Comment: Got it but confused how the $\frac{1}{2}$ arises

Comment: ${\large\pi\,\delta\left(k\right)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\int_0^\infty\cos(kr)\,dr=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\cos(kr)\,dr=\frac{1}{2}\text{Re}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\cos(kr)+i\sin(kr)\,dr\right).$$Now use the fact that $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ to get $$\frac{1}{2}\text{Re}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikr}\,dr\right).$$